# Question repeated in iOS app question list

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, ios-app

See screenshot here:

[image]

A question was repeated as you can see (sorry I do not know how to circle on my phone)

Comment: YOUR SCREENSHOT IS YELLING AT ME IT IS SO LARGE

Comment: Haha sorry @wont I had to upload it through a different app and then copy the link. There is no upload image option via the app yet

Comment: @lowerclass what do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Deduplication with ordered sets only works if you set the hash and equality functions.  Fixed in the next build.